# How Can I Automatically Post Wordpress Posts to 2 Domains

Tags: multisite

I am setting up a travel website on both a .com and .uk domain using wordpress. I want to be able to share the posts across two domains, i.e. publish a post on domain.com and have it appear on domain.co.uk.

The domains are localised for American and British English. On the American site the category page is for vacation rentals and on the British site (.co.uk) the posts are categorized as holiday rentals.

How can I post on one blog and synchronize between the two while still keeping unique categories?

Comment: Do you want *all* posts cross-posted?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network) is what you're looking for.